# gRPC with C# - "2 UNKNOWN: Stream remove"

Tags: c#, grpc

I have created very simple gRPC server. 
It's a template project from Microsoft.

[image]

`csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.24.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`Program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    // Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
    // For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
}
```

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

            endpoints.MapGet("/",
                async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                        "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
                });
        });
    }
}
```

`GreeterService`

```
public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;

    public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
        {
            Message = "Hello " + request.Name
        });
    }
}
```

And my proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcServiceTest";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I think, You know this template. I run it:

[image]

Then I'm trying to connect via my RPC client `BloomRPC` and I see the following error:

[image]

Why? What is wrong?

Comment: question: does it work from a different gRPC client? perhaps the Google or Microsoft .NET client APIs? I'm wondering if this is something odd about the way BloomRPC is communicating

Comment: (also: do you have "fiddler" or similar running? fiddler is notorious for breaking http2 currently)

Comment: @MarcGravell I did not try. I worked with gRPC a couple of months ago, with this client and I did not have any problems. Thank you for idea, I will check new one gRPC client.

Comment: @MarcGravell about the fiddler - no. I even have not installed it)

Answer (score 2):

It is not working on port 5001 without HTTPS certificate.
There are 2 options to fix it.

1. Add HTTP(non HTTPS) endpoint.
   To do that update `applicationUrl` in `launchSettings.json` to have 2 endpoints:

   ```
      ...
     "ProfileWeb": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
         },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
     },
       ...
   ```

Use port `5000` instead of 5001 in `BloomRPC`

2. Add SSL certificate in TLS/SSL Manager in `BloomRPC`[image]